# iPhone css hover, forces me to add a touch event

Tags: iphone, css, events, hover, touch

How come I need to add a touch event to my element for it to enable hover styles?
Is this normal? Sure feels a bit wonky

This is what I have to add to make :hover work, if I don't no :hover style is set
*sorry for the coffeescript*

```
@button.$el.on('touchstart', ()->
    console.log("touch started")
)
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? I couldn't find anything 'prolonged touch'-related to css / javascript

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330559/hover-effects-using-css3-touch-events) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i took a look at what *Roddy of the Frozen Peas* linked and found that you could add 'ontouchstart=""' to the element to enable hover styles.

What I realised though, was that it's enough to add it to the super parent, and it will bubble down to all child elements, neat-O!

Comment: This is the solution. I have been looking for an answer to this problem for an hour.

Comment: exactly what I needed.  Also, don't forget to add on("touchend",function() {...} if you want to clear it.  +1