# CSS :hover behaviour on touchscreen devices

Tags: html, css

I am developing a CSS framework that relies on being **simple, minimal and pure CSS** as much as possible. What I want is to to make certain things like dropdowns open on hover, however I am uncertain how to go about implementing this with only CSS on mobile devices.

Having checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427465/1650200) previously, I confirmed what I partially knew to be true: that certain mobile browsers and devices will use the `:hover` pseudo-class when clicking an element, which will allow me to open dropdowns the way I want. Others say that `:active` works as well.

I am using both in one rule, as well as `:focus` to cover as many environments and cases as possible, however I am not certain this will work well across many devices. So my questions are:

- Is there any way to make sure a hover-based dropdown component will work across devices?
- Are there pseudo-classes or properties that I can use that might be browser-specific or something similar to make sure that most devices are covered?
- Is there documentation about touchscreen, mobile device or mobile browser behaviour and how they handle hover events?

Comment: From the marketing perspective, it is not a good practice to use hover on tap-devices. Common users don't know how to use it properly. It confuses them and they leave. Users like to tap on big colorful buttons.

Comment: @cdm what you say sounds very much correct and logical to me. Do you have anything better to suggest? Do you propose I turn my dropdowns into buttons that work by clicking (using the checkbox-hack to make them pure CSS or similar)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is nearly a duplicate of a bunch of questions out there, but I want to address your main points:

1. By "a hover based dropdown" you mean one that will appear as long as the user has their finger on it? As a mobile user, I can't picture this being a successful UX
2. All pseudo-classes are here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes The ones I would consider "interactive" are `:active`, `:checked`, `:focus`, `:hover`. The trouble with `:hover` is, as you say, it isn't well supported and, again, it doesn't really fit the way users interact with mobile sites. The trouble with `:checked` is it relies on checkboxes, which puts pretty severe restrictions on the supported markup.
3. Definitely mobile Safari doesn't support it, which means it's a big enough problem to matter.

The most common solution is to use javascript touchevents, but if you're going all-CSS that isn't going to work for you.

You may find something useful here [Hover effects using CSS3 touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330559/hover-effects-using-css3-touch-events) or here [:touch CSS pseudo-class or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063308/touch-css-pseudo-class-or-something-similar)

Comment: As far as (1) is concerned I was thinking something like what Firefox for Android does, which is it applies a hover style on the first click. However, what you are describing definitely feels awkward and is exactly what I want to avoid, that's why I am asking how exactly mobile devices handle these kinds of events. As for the rest, I think that Safari's lack of support is a big enough no-no for me, so I should maybe try something different. I will check the links you provided, thank you very much!