# How to add mouseover effects on a touchpad / touch device?

Tags: css, touch

I'm looking for a solution for using a hover effect on touch screens and I have no idea how to start this.

I made a Fiddle of my hover-effect:

I've read some tutorials using javascript, but didn't get this to work and I'm not really into js. Can anyone help me out? The appreciated link does not help me, sorry.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h7vkupwe/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :hover behaviour on touchscreen devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325682/css-hover-behaviour-on-touchscreen-devices)

Comment: Please @Dublay update your question, do not add informations in comments.

Comment: I was not able to add the fiddle into the question, sorry!